# DL4J - What is the URL of dataexamples for deep learning 4 J?

Tags: dl4j

Anybody knows where download DataExamples of Deep Learning 4J? Looks like this URL is old.

Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://deeplearning4jblob.blob.core.windows.net/dl4j-examples/dl4j-examples/DataExamples.zip

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if someone has the same problem.

New URL : https://dl4jdata.blob.core.windows.net/dl4j-examples